# enum declare method for call

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I've rephrase my post to better explain.
I'd like to compare objects but not using reflection or annotation to declare fields mappings but use enum for mapping and functional programming, what I mean

```
enum MyEnum {
  PERSON_LAST_NAME("lastName", Person::getLastName(), PersonEntity::getLstName())
}
```

and now having instances of Person and PersonsEntity and I would like to iterate MyEnum values call these declared methods on my objects.
Just to wanted to replace the code with more generic solution

```
  Person person = getPerson();
  Person personEntity = getPersonEntity();
  if (Objects.equals(person.getLastName(), personEntity.getLstName()) {
   return "lastName";
  }
  if (Objects.equals(person.getFirstName(), personEntity.getFstName()) {
   return "firstName";
  }
```

Comment: Can you show how you want to use `MyEnum`?

Comment: You can add a constructor to your enum that accepts some suppliers as arguments, if that's what you want.

Comment: You didn’t ask a question.

Comment: The question is it possible replace the code with more generic solution i..e using enum to store field mappings

Comment: What's the difference/relation between `Person` and `PersonEntity`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with an enum, because you'll need generics.
You can achieve it with a class though.

Based on the code snippet from the question I am assuming `Person` is an interface and `PersonEntity` implements it

But allow me to disclaim that unless you know very well what you're doing I'd say your going down a bad route with this approach, but for implementation's sake here's a generic solution using functions.

```
class FieldComparator<T, V> {
  public static final List< FieldComparator<Person, ?>> PERSON_FIELD_COMPARATORS = List.of(
    new FieldComparator<>("firstName", Person::getFirstName),
    new FieldComparator<>("lastName", Person::getLastName),
    new FieldComparator<>("birthDate", Person::getBirthDate)
  );

  private final String fieldName;
  private final Function<T, V> function;

  public FieldComparator(String fieldName, Function<T, V> function) {
    this.fieldName = fieldName;
    this.function = function;
  }

  public boolean equals(T t1, T t2) {
    return Objects.equals(function.apply(t1), function.apply(t2));
  }

  public String getFieldName() {
    return fieldName;
  }
}
```

Using iteration:

```
Person person = getPerson();
Person personEntity = getPersonEntity();

for (FieldComparator<Person, ?> fieldComparator : FieldComparator.PERSON_FIELD_COMPARATORS) {
  if (fieldComparator.equals(person, personEntity)) {
    return fieldComparator.getFieldName();
  }
}

return null;
```

Using streams:

```
Person person = getPerson();
Person personEntity = getPersonEntity();

return FieldComparator.PERSON_FIELD_COMPARATORS.stream()
  .filter(fieldComparator -> fieldComparator.equals(person, personEntity))
  .map(FieldComparator::getFieldName)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(null);
```